# How to close all Tool Windows In VS2008 with single key shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for to bind or use an existing shortcut to close all visible tool windows in VS2008.

There was an add-in for VS2005 to do this, but it  doesn't seem to work in VS2008.

Comment: A tad too effective for my taste ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools->Options->Keyboard->Assign key for `Window.AutoHideAll` command.

With <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> you can close active toolbox.

Comment: Using Window.AutoHideAll and at the same time uncheck "Animate environment tools" under Options->General will be an acceptable solution. Too bad that the tabs are visible, but I can live with that :o) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to switch to Full Screen mode, this will automatically hide all the windows.

Comment: When I open a tool window when in FullSceen mode it will be remembered and opened again next time I enter Full Screen mode.